# Socket.io server ping timeout on some connections

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm having issues with using the socket.io JS client and the server where websocket connections ping timeout at random times. I've searched high and low through SO and the rest of the interwebs.

Some context on the project - this is an Electron/ReactJS application that has two separate windows, where the socket.io client connects on application load, provided the user is logged in. If a user logs in after application load, the same function to connect to the socket is called:

```
  const protocol = Env.isDev() ? 'http' : 'https'
  const socketServer = `${protocol}://${LocalConfig.servers.websocket}:80`
  const socketReceiverId = createReceiverId()

  /**
   * Initiates the websocket connection
   */
  export function init() {

    // Get authourizer ID
    const authorizerId = getAuthId()

    // only allow in the renderer and we have an authorizer id
    // and if the socket connection is null. Socket will not be
    // null if this method is called after HMR
    if (Env.isRenderer() && authorizerId && !getCurrentSocket()) {
      const socket = sockio(`${socketServer}/notification`, {
        timeout: 5000,
        reconnection: false,
        transportOptions: {
          polling: {
            extraHeaders: {
              'origin': `gui://${process.env.PLATFORM}`,
              'x-receiver-token': socketReceiverId,
              'x-authorization': authorizerId
            }
          }
        }
      })
      socket.on('s:connected', onConnected) // called when connection made (custom event with extra data
        .on('n:push', onNotification)       // called when a notification is received
        .on('s:close', onServerClose)       // called when server shuts down
        .on('disconnect', onDisconnect)     // called on disconnect
        .on('error', console.warn)
    }
  }
```

I had to leave `reconnection` to `false` because I need to manage reconnections manually, because if a user logs out, we won't be reconnecting, but will reconnect after successful login

I'm also using polling so I can send extra headers, including origin, authorization and the `receiver-token`, which is a random UUID that's stored in LocalStorage to uniquely identify the application instance, and will be the `room` that we join, so notifications get sent to the proper device, whether it's this app or mobile (which will all use the same websocket interface)

When the application loads initially and the websocket connection is attempted, 90% of the time, *both* windows connect successfully and the push notifications come through - the other 10% of the time, only one window can connect, while the other won't (even though through logging on the client, I can see that the `onConnected` callback is called). Eventually, both will connect successfully, but ideally, they should connect instantly at the first attempt.

What really screws things up is when the server reboots (which will be something that will happen from time to time, as new code gets pushed to the server and the service is restarted). When the server disconnects however, a message is emitted to all clients currently connected where the custom reconnect circuit is invoked.

This is where the main issues start - whether it's manual reconnection, or automatic, the polling keeps failing with a `ping timeout` error, even though the `onConnected` callback is called.

Eventually, the connections all settle and connect - sometimes after a minute or two, sometimes as much as 10 minutes to a half hour. It's all exceedingly random.

Note that everything right now is on my local machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, so there should be near zero latency.

I pasted the verbose debug output here:
https://pastebin.com/TR6qPe0R

Here is the main server code:

```
import process from 'process'
import http from 'http'
import sockio from 'socket.io'
import { BindAll } from 'lodash-decorators'
import { Handlers } from './Handlers'
import { Receiver } from './Receiver'
import { RedisPool } from './RedisPool'
import { Log } from './Logger'

interface NamespaceGroup {
  ns: SocketIO.Namespace
  receiver: Receiver
}

@BindAll()
class Server {

  private _port: number
  private _socketServer: sockio.Server
  private _pollingServer: http.Server
  private _namespaces: NamespaceGroup[] = []

  constructor() {
    this._port = parseInt(process.env['PORT']) || 18000
    this._pollingServer = http.createServer(Handlers.handleHttpRequest)
  }

  startServer() {
    this._pollingServer.listen(this._port, this.onServerStart)
    process.on('SIGINT', this.close)
    process.on('SIGUSR2', this.close)
  }

  private async onServerStart() {

    Log.info(`Server started on port ${this._port}`)

    this._socketServer = sockio(this._pollingServer)
    this._socketServer.origins(Handlers.handleOrigin)
    this._socketServer.use(Handlers.handleAuthorization)

    const nsNotify = this._socketServer.of('/notification')
      .on('connection', Handlers.handleNotificationConnection)

    this._namespaces.push({
      ns: nsNotify,
      receiver: new Receiver(nsNotify)
    })
  }

  private close() {
    Log.info('Closing server. Killing process')
    for (const nsGroup of this._namespaces) {
      nsGroup.ns.emit('s:close')
    }
    this._socketServer.close()
    RedisPool.closeAll()
    process.exit(0)
  }
}

const server = new Server()
export default server
```

And the handlers:

```
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http'
import { Socket } from 'socket.io'
import { Queries } from './Queries'
import { Log } from './Logger'
import { OutgoingMessage } from './Receiver'

export namespace Handlers {

  const allowedOrigins = [
    'gui://win32',
    'gui://darwin',
    'gui://linux',
    'ast://android',
    'ast://ios',
    'mob://android',
    'mob://ios',
  ]

  export function handleOrigin(origin: string, callback: (error: string | null, success: boolean) => void) {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) == -1) {
      callback('Invalid Origin: ' + origin, false)
    } else {
      callback(null, true)
    }
  }

  export async function handleAuthorization(socket: Socket, next: (err?: any) => void) {

    const auth = socket.handshake.headers['x-authorization']
    const receiverToken = socket.handshake.headers['x-receiver-token']

    if (!auth) {
      next(new Error('Authorization not provided'))
      socket.disconnect()
    } else {
      try {
        const credentials = await Queries.findClientCredentials(auth)
        if (!!credentials) {
          await Queries.saveCurrentToken(auth, receiverToken)
          next()
        } else {
          Log.warn('Client rejected [auth:%s] (Invalid Authorization)', auth)
          next(new Error('Invalid Authorization: ' + auth))
          socket.disconnect()
        }
      } catch (err) {
        next(err)
        Log.error('Client auth error', err)
        socket.disconnect()
      }
    }
  }

  export async function handleNotificationConnection(socket: Socket) {

    const auth = socket.handshake.headers['x-authorization']
    const receiverToken = socket.handshake.headers['x-receiver-token']

    const namespace = socket.nsp
    const ns = namespace.name

    // Emit connection message
    socket.emit('s:connected', ns, socket.id) // lets the client know connection is OK

    // Join room specific to an application instance
    socket.join(receiverToken)

    Log.debug('Connect: Client connected to %s [auth:%s] - %s (%d active sockets)',
      ns, auth, socket.id, socket.adapter.rooms[receiverToken].length)

    // Listens to the c:close (client request close) event
    socket.on('c:close', async reason => {
      socket.leave(receiverToken)
      socket.disconnect(true)
      Log.debug('Disconnect: (%s) %s : %s', reason, receiverToken, socket.id)
    })
  }

  // Default HTTP handler for the main Node HTTP server
  export function handleHttpRequest(request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse) {
    response.statusCode = 200
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    response.end(`${request.method} ${request.url}\n`)
  }
}
```

The rest of the code on the server side works as it should, such as `RedisPool` and the `Receiver` class instances. The issue is with connectivity, so I only included the `Server` class and `Handlers` namespace.

And on the client, the relevant code (same namespace as the `init` function above):

```
  // Flag to tell us if the disconnection
  // was instigated via the client after a
  // log out, so we know if we need to
  // reconnect
  let isManualDisconnect = false

  /**
   * Manually disconnect from the websocket server
   * normally used when user logs out
   */
  export function disconnect() {
    const socket = getCurrentSocket()
    isManualDisconnect = true // lets us know not to attempt reconnects
    socket.emit('c:close', 'manual client disconnect', socket.id)
  }

  /**
   * Handle a successful connection to the websocket server
   * @param ns the namespace connected to (should always be /notification)
   * @param socketId the socket id (SID)
   */
  function onConnected(ns: string, socketId: string) {
    console.log('Connection to %s Accepted. Receiver ID: %s', ns, socketId)
    isManualDisconnect = false
  }

  /**
   * Handles the disconnection from the socket server
   * @param reason the reason for the disconnect
   */
  function onDisconnect(reason: DisconnectReason) {
    console.log('Disconnected (%s) Manual:', reason, isManualDisconnect)
    if (!isManualDisconnect) {
      if (getAuthId())
        getCurrentSocket().connect()
    }
  }

  /**
   * Handles a socket being disconnected when the
   * socket server shuts down
   */
  function onServerClose() {
    console.log('Socket server interrupt')
    window.setTimeout(reconnect, 5000)
  }

  /**
   * Attempts a reconnection every 5 seconds until
   * a conneciton is re-established
   */
  function reconnect() {
    const socket = getCurrentSocket()
    console.log('Attempting reconnect')
    if (socket.disconnected) {
      console.log('Socket confirmed disconnected. Opening...')
      socket.open()
    } else {
      window.setTimeout(reconnect, 5000)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the current authorization id from local storage
   */
  function getAuthId(): string {
    return window.localStorage.getItem('auth')
  }

  function getCurrentSocket(): SocketIOClient.Socket {
    const manager = sockio.managers[socketServer]
    if (manager)
      return manager.nsps['/notification']
  }

  /**
   * Gets the current receiver id (application instance id)
   */
  export function getReceiverId(): string {
    return socketReceiverId
  }
```

Finally, the NGINX config for the socket server:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     [server name here];
    location / {
        proxy_pass          "http://127.0.0.1:18000";
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
    }
}
```

I realize the code examples are verbose, but I've tinkered for over a day trying to find the issue, but with no solutions. Another issue is that nearly all examples for socket.io involve chat applications that don't cover authorization, origins, or how to properly disconnect, and in which order.

Socket.io client and server versions are the same (2.2.0)

Comment: did you solved this`?